# Debian install on new laptop: turning on network device?

Tags: networking, system-installation

I've got a brand new laptop. The stable Debian wouldn't launch GNOME though, nor find a driver for the network device. The latest unstable did it. Now, there is no ethernet socket, no Wifi is showing up, and in the menu for the network I have no option to set it up. I don't know how to turn on the network device or enable the Wifi.

I've been able to gather the information below through the Terminal.

What situation am I looking at? What should be the next steps from there?

Note: it seems the network device is recent and that its series is badly supported in linux. Is the kernel module attributed in the install (`rtw88_8822ce`) appropriate for that device? (or where could I find the information?)

```bsh
~$ nmcli general status
STATE            CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW    WIFI       WWAN-HW    WWAN      
not connected    unknown       activated  activated  activated  activated 

~$ sudo lshw -numeric -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10EC:C822]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. [10EC]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0800000-d080ffff

~$ networkctl
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

IDX LINK TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP    
  1 lo   loopback n/a         unmanaged

1 links listed.

~$ nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (nicht verwaltet)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256

~$ lspci -vv -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 24
    IOMMU group: 8
    Region 0: I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Via message/WAKE#, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [148 v1] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-c8-22-01
    Capabilities: [158 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 1048576ns
        Max no snoop latency: 1048576ns
    Capabilities: [160 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=30us PortTPowerOnTime=60us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=32768ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=150us
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtek RTL8822CE appears to be supported since [kernel 5.2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=6ffe0acc935f344eb0b35da07c034d5122222e77):

> wireless-drivers-next patches for 5.2
>
> Most likely the last patchset of new feature for 5.2, and this time we
> have quite a lot of new features. Most obvious being rtw88 from
> Realtek which supports RTL8822BE and **RTL8822CE** 802.11ac devices.

The option [`CONFIG_RTW88_8822CE`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTW88_8822CE.html) option and its module `rtw88_8822ce.ko` [is present](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&arch=any&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=rtw88_8822ce.ko) in current Debian bullseye/unstable.

Reading this randomly found thread: [Driver for Realteck RTL8822CE](https://www.linux.org/threads/driver-for-realteck-rtl8822ce.29172/):

> Found that because of the errors, according to
> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2448425, that not having
> rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin in the rtw88 folder meant thtat I needed to update
> my firmware to 1.187.2...

And checking the availability of the firmware file on Debian bullseye (it would be the result for unstable currently) using again [Search the contents of packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin&mode=path&suite=bullseye&arch=any) on https://packages.debian.org/ :

> `File                                     Packages`
> `/lib/firmware/rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin` [`firmware-realtek`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-realtek)

leads me to think you have to:

- enable the contrib and non-free repository if not already done. You can replace *bullseye* with *unstable* if that's what you had, but better not. Put this in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

  ```
  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
  ```
- and install *firmware-realtek*:

  ```
  # apt-get update
  # apt-get install firmware-realtek
  ```

But actually there's a chicken-and-eggs problem if no network connectivity is available. You can still download this package from elsewhere, copy it with an USB key and install it with `dpkg -i firmware-realtek_20200918-1_all.deb`. Here's (today's) relevant information about it for this:

```
$ apt-get --print-uris download firmware-realtek/bullseye
'http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-realtek_20200918-1_all.deb' firmware-realtek_20200918-1_all.deb 716200 SHA256:24d487082fd805f9c37236df0d17a7ec157849837490113c8fc9407229acb58f
```

so you can check the checksum matches even if downloaded over an "insecure" channel.

Comment: You saved my life! This package did it through USB.